# Floodlight Recommendation

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, backyard

I have a half acre backyard and I'm looking for ways to keep it bright enough since I host a lot of functions in the yard. I already have a Google Nest cam with floodlight and 3 lights that operate on Solar, but it's not enough to light up the entire yard.

I am thinking on the lines of getting 1 or 2 floodlights installed on the top of the back of the house, since it should give me good coverage and also might be easier to run the wiring from the attic. What are my other options here? The lights need not necessarily be motion sensor controlled.

Comment: "bright enough" so enough to just see the path or to play football?

Comment: Seems like you've given us 2 of the same pic. Would also be useful to know the rough shape and dimensions (not just the area) of the space you want lit up.

Comment: "Bright enough" to see or "bright enough" for photos/video?

Comment: get some actual landscape lighting, not jailbreak floodlights. It's not that expensive these days, and there's a HUGE difference of how the two will look, perform, and make guests feel. I've never heard anyone regret adding landscape lighting, except that they should have done it years ago. Lights should be as close to the people needing them as practically and aesthetically possible to avoid blinders, light pollution, and distorted shadows.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an square field: Half an acre would yield a square with ~44m side lengths.
Floodlights on the side of your house would just throw long shadows.

If good lights are really important I'd install an central lightpole, or multiple distributed lights.

Answer (score 1):

Your options are limited; your location of Hillsborough Township has light pollution regulations. Total light intensity, height of fixture and light spillage onto other properties and into the sky are all regulated.

Details at https://ecode360.com/10255331

> § 188-57 Lighting. All area lighting shall provide for lights focused
> downward, translucent fixtures and shielding or such other light
> orientation and shielding as to prevent light spillage off the site.
> The light intensity provided at ground level shall be a minimum of 0.3
> footcandle anywhere and shall average a maximum of 0.5 footcandle over
> the entire area. No light source shall exceed a height of 15 feet. For
> each fixture and lighted sign, the total quantity of light radiated
> above a horizontal plane passing through the light source shall not
> exceed 7 1/2% of the total quantity of light emitted from the light
> source. Any outdoor lighting shall be shown on the site plan in
> sufficient detail to allow determination of the effects at the
> property line and on nearby streets, driveways, residences and
> overhead sky glow. The objective of these specifications is to
> minimize undesirable off-site effects. No light shall shine directly
> into windows or onto streets and driveways in such a manner as to
> create a nuisance or interfere with or distract driver vision. To
> achieve these requirements, the intensity of such light sources, light
> shielding and similar characteristics shall be subject to site plan
> approval.